# Retrieve auto increment id of last inserted record in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

MVC 4 has been a very tough nut to crack for me. I am using three tables in a SQL Compact database.

`Accounts` Table is saved first (which I have done) but the `Phones` and `Data` table use `AccountsID` as a foreign key. MVC 4 does all the database work through the `Model` and the `View` so how can I get `AccountsID` from the newly added row in the Database through MVC 4 and  provided it to the Phones and Data Models so everything saves correctly?

Comment: After calling `context.SaveChanges()` the newly added entity will have the `id` that the database created.

Answer (score 9):

You can do the following:

```
var account = new Account();
context.Accounts.Add(account);
context.SaveChanges();

var Phone = new Phone();
// account.Id will be populated with the Id from the Database.
// as long as it's the identity seed or set to NewID()(Sql Server)
phone.AccountId = account.Id;
...
```